# VueJS - How to initialize a template dynamically with the result of an ajax call

Tags: javascript, mvvm, coffeescript, vue.js

I want to load the `template` for a VueJS component dynamically.  I'd like to make an AJAX call using jQuery, and whatever the server returns should be the `template` of the VueJS component.  Here's a simplified version of the code with the AJAX call removed since it's irrelevant where the data is coming from:

```
BoardFeed = Vue.extend
    template: '<div>This should be replaced</div>'
    data: ->
            return items: null
    created: ->
        @template = "<div>Template returned from server, what I really want</div>"
```

In the above example I'm using the [created](http://vuejs.org/api/options.html#created) hook which I thought would be suitable for this, but the newer template is never rendered, only the older one.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `v-partial` in your template. And when you've loaded the partial, you can register it via `Vue.partial()`. The `{{ partial }}` value is then replaced, thus rendering the new partial.

```
BoardFeed = Vue.extend
    template: '<div v-partial="{{ partial }}">This should be replaced</div>'
    partials: {"beforeLoad": "<div>This should be replaced</div>"}
    data: ->
            return {items: null, partial: "beforeLoad"}
    created: ->
        Vue.partial("afterLoad", "<div>Template returned from server, what I really want</div>")
        @partial = "afterLoad"
```

(and excuse any coffee-script errors, I'm not very familiar with it)